# Azure Search: Cache ServiceClient without depending on index name in v11

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I currently use v10 of the Azure Search APIs and create a static variable like so:

```
private static SearchServiceClient SearchServiceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, credentials);
```

On the server side, this variable is re-used between requests so I don't have to initialize it over and over. I got the idea from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections to improve performance.

Now, v11 has completely different data types. The new `SearchClient` type's [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Search_Documents_SearchClient__ctor_System_Uri_System_String_Azure_AzureKeyCredential_) expects an index name as a parameter. I have many indexes and I'd like to avoid creating a static variable for each index,

In v11, is it possible to re-use a search client in the way I used to be able to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v11, the `SearchServiceClient` is actually split into 3 different clients: `SearchClient`, `SearchIndexClient`, `SearchIndexerClient`, each of them has different usage. You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-dotnet-sdk-migration-version-11#client-differences) for the details.

So when you use `SearchClient`, it is defined to have an index name parameter. You can not re-use it like what `SearchServiceClient` does in v10.

But you can do it like below:

```
SearchIndexClient adminClient = new SearchIndexClient(serviceEndpoint, credential); 

SearchClient ingesterClient = adminClient.GetSearchClient(indexName);
```

Comment: Is re-creating a `SearchClient` over and over performant with every request the server receives?

Comment: @user246392. Yes, it will. The proper way may create a `SearchIndexClient` first -> then use its `GetSearchClient` method to fetch a `SearchClient`. Sample code like below: `SearchIndexClient adminClient = new SearchIndexClient(serviceEndpoint, credential); SearchClient ingesterClient = adminClient.GetSearchClient(indexName);`

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.